# Define if statement for property in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, properties

```
public class hamid
{
    private int[] arr = new int[10];
    public int[] Arr 
    { 
        get => arr; 
        set 
        { 
            if (value < 0) 
                Environment.Exit(1); 
            else arr = value; 
        } 
    } // If in error.
}
```

I want have a `if` statement. For example `if (values < 0)`
But I have an error, please help me.

Comment: You need to provide more context and actually ask a question.  Include what you have tried, what doesn't work and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: public class hamid
    {
        private int[] arr = new int[10];
        public int[] Arr
        {
            get
            {
                return arr;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    arr = value;
                }
            }
        }
//if in error

Comment: Don't add a comment with clarification, edit your question to provide more context.  Comments are not formatted and are hard to read.

Comment: How are we supposed to help when you've given us no information whatsoever about what the error is, what you're trying to do, nothing.

Comment: @hamid What exactly are you trying to do? `value` is an `int[]`, not `int` so it's value will never be zero. What were you expecting? Are you trying to set an element of the array, or set the array to something else?

Comment: I want the program to stop if the user enters a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is an array of integer, it can't be zero.  Any element in the array could be zero.  If you are trying to determine if the array is null, then you could change the check to be:

```
if (value == null) 
{
     Environment.Exit(1); 
}
```

Comment: I want the program to stop if the user enters a negative number.